# Determining homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

I am asked to determine if the following mapping is a homomorphism:

Define $\phi\colon D_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_4$ by $\phi(r^kf) = k$.

I have deduced that $\phi(f) = 0$ as $\phi(f) = \phi(r^0f) = 0$. However, I am having trouble determining $\phi(r^m)$ for $ 0\le m<4$. My intuition tells me that $\phi$ is indeed a homomorphism, but $\ker(\phi)  = \{e,f\}$, which is not a normal subgroup of $D_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the intention was to define
$$\phi(r^kf)=\phi(r^k)=k.$$
Recall that in $D_4$, we have $frf=r^3$, but since $$\phi(f)+\phi(rf)=0+1=1$$ doesn't equal $$\phi(frf)=\phi(r^3)=3$$ we see that $\phi$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: Should we not test whether $\phi(frf) = \phi(r^3)$ rather than the product $\phi(f)\phi(rf) $ that you have used?

Comment: @Kevin: Because $frf=r^3$, it is necessarily the case that $\phi(frf)=\phi(r^3)$. That's what equality means, if $a=b$ then anything I do with $a$ I can do with $b$ and get the same result. The test of being a homomorphism is whether the function $\phi$ respects the operation of the groups it's mapping between,
$$\phi(g_1\cdot g_2)=\phi(g_1)\star\phi(g_2)$$

Comment: That's exactly my point, why did you use $\phi(f)\phi(rf)$ rather than $\phi(frf)$?

Comment: We are testing whether
$$\phi(f\cdot rf)=\phi(f)+\phi(rf)$$
They're not equal so $\phi$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: Ah, I think my confusion stems from a typo; I think you forgot a plus sign in your answer?

Comment: I see, yeah I did miss a plus sign; added it now.